# Les douzaines et les grosses

Tags: expressions, nombres

Il me semble que le fait de compter en base 10 est très ancien (par exemple le décompte des armées dans *la Guerre des Gaules* se fait en millier).

Alors d'où vient l'habitude de compter en douzaine et en douzaine de douzaine (ce qu'on appelle une grosse) ? Un rapport peut-être avec le nombre de mois dans l'année ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas du français, c'est de l'histoire des mathématiques et de l'astronomie, notamment chez les Babyloniens et les Égyptiens, qui divisent l'année en douze mois à cause de la lune et qui divisent le jour et la nuit en douze heures chacun à cause de la division du mois en trois décans, et qui utilisent aussi la base soixante (nos minutes et secondes) qui contient douze cinq fois. Les explications détaillées tiennent dans une bonne partie du livre de référence _Les sciences exactes dans l'antiquité_ d'Otto Neugebauer.

Comment: Compter en base douze est utilisé par les astronomes et mathématiciens dès la plus haute antiquité - comme le dit mouviciel. Adopté vraisemblablement par les astronomes et mathématiciens parce que douze est un petit nombre avec beaucoup de diviseurs (il a 6 diviseurs, plus que 8 et 10). Pouvoir faire des opérations en calculant de tête (la division est une opération complexe surtout quand elle a un reste) est probablement ce qui a fait perdurer la base douze dans les transactions commerciales alors que la base dix s'est imposée chez la plupart parce que nous pouvons compter sur nos dix doigts.

Answer (score 3):

Une réponse directement du journal *Ca m'intéresse !*

> C'est l'héritage d'unités de mesures du Moyen Age, qui utilisaient la base 12. Longueur : pieds de 12 pouces ; poids : livre de 12 onces ; monnaies : sols à 12 deniers. A l'origine de ce choix, il y a la possibilité de compter jusqu'à 12 avec son pouce les 12 phalanges des 4 autres doigts de la main, et ce, en manipulant des objets de l'autre main. De plus, 12 est divisible par 6, 4, 3 et 2, ce qui facilite les calculs. Aujourd'hui, la base décimale a remplacé la base 12, mais on compte toujours certains produits par douzaines comme les oeufs.

[source](http://www.caminteresse.fr/questions_reponses/les_qr/histoire/pourquoi_vend_on_les_huitres_par_douzaines)

Answer (score 3):

Il ne s'agit pas du tout d'une spécificité française.

La coexistence de plusieurs bases de numération incluant la numération duodécimale est attestée dans de nombreuses civilisations, à commencer par les Sumériens. On la retrouve chez les Égyptiens et les Romains.

Douze est le nombre d'heures de la journée et de la nuit, le nombre de constellations du zodiaque, de mois dans l'année ou de pouces dans un pied (mesure de distance de la Rome antique encore utilisée dans le monde anglo-saxon).

Cinq fois douze est le nombre de secondes dans une minute et de minutes dans une heure.

Trente fois douze le nombre de degrés dans un cercle.